# Visual Studio 2019 TypeScript build erorrs after adding site.ts and then nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 (v16.11.5) I added a site.ts file and some ts code.
VS prompted me to install the nuget package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild, which I did.
Now on site.ts save site.js is produced just fine, however, now VS won't build the solution and produce a number of TS errors (see screenshot).

When I remove Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild the solution builds, but site.ts does not compile on save.

Any idea about what I'm missing (package/setting/other)?

I have a gulpfile.js which I guess could also handle the ts compilation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-nuget?view=vs-2019 turns out I was missing a tsconfig.json file in project root.

I added this to the file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "include": [
    "Scripts/site.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @mortenma71, please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and thanks for sharing the solution:)

Comment: Hi @Tianyu it's done. Didn't realise I had to accept my own answer :-)